# Why is bundler loading all my gems instead of specific ones

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a Sinatra application and I'm trying to use groups in my Gemfile in order to load only specified gems. But, when I restrict loading to just one group bundler still loads every gem in the file. Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :one do
  gem 'sinatra'
end

group :two do 
  gem 'bitly'
end
```

And here's my application:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:one)

class App < Sinatra::Base

  configure do
    puts Gem.loaded_specs.keys.sort.join("\t")
  end

  get '/foo' do
  end

end
```

And I can clearly see the Bitly gem loaded when the application starts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963836/why-does-bundle-install-production-gems-on-my-development-machine/6963907#6963907)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
require 'bundler'
```

instead of

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

The last one automatically loads all gems in Gemfile: [Why do you need "require 'bundler/setup'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243486/why-do-you-need-require-bundler-setup)